# VB.net Custom Textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

i am using a custom textbox control which doesn't have Text.Split() function in this box i enter a string in the follwing format : "35 To 99" , now here is my code i know its wrong, my programming skills are limited

```
    Dim v1 As Int32
    Dim v2 As Int32
    Dim rule As New String("{0} To {1}", v1, v2) = TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox(v1 & " " & v2)
```

in other words how would you get the nubers in this string "35 To 99" assign each one to a variable without Text.Split()

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have the `Text.Split` method?  Your example shows it having a `Text` property, which is presumably a string.  If it is a string, then it does indeed have the `Split` method.

Comment: just discovered that it does :D, but how to do it using the string formmating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split` is a method of the `String` class, not the `TextBox` class.  As such, it doesn't matter where you get the string from, whether it be from a text box, a custom control, a file, or anywhere else, you can use the `String.Split` method to split it.  For instance:

```
Dim v1 As Int32
Dim v2 As Int32
Dim rule As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim parts() As String = rule.Split(New String() {" To "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
v1 = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
v2 = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
MessageBox.Show(v1 & " " & v2)
```

Or, more tersely:

```
' ...
Dim parts() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {" To "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
' ...
```

To make the split case insensitive, just force the case one way or the other on the whole string before you split it, for instance:

```
Dim parts() As String = TextBox1.Text.ToLower().Split(New String() {" to "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

or

```
Dim parts() As String = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper().Split(New String() {" TO "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: but how to make it ignore the case like To to tO all as split